# Qcache_hits always 0

Tags: mysql, caching, centos

On Centos 6.3 I'm trying to enable query caching on Mysql.
I have enabled query caching

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache_size';
query_cache_size    52428800

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache_type';
query_cache_type    ON
```

When running a few simple select queries (select * from titles), the Qcache_hits always stays 0.

(I'm using these sample mysql database: https://launchpad.net/test-db/+download)

```
show status like "Qcache%";
Qcache_free_blocks  1
Qcache_free_memory  52419904
Qcache_hits 0
Qcache_inserts  0
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0
Qcache_not_cached   50
Qcache_queries_in_cache 0
Qcache_total_blocks 1
```

I'm out of options figuring out what's wrong here.
Does anyone have an idea what can be wrong?

Comment: What is the database name? Does it have `-`?

Comment: Another possible cause if someone hits similar issues: [mysql bug #55556: Query Cache not used when database name contains minus and table is innodb](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55556).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably missed the [query_cache_limit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_limit) option, which prevents resultsets larger than this from being cached.

You may also have a non-standard setting for [query_cache_type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_type).

Comment: that's it! Thanks for pointing that out! However, now that Qcache gets hit, the profiler shows that the query still takes 2.4 seconds to complete, the same as before the cache got hit. Is that normal for a select * query?

Comment: No, this is quite odd, indeed. You may want to post a new question with the profiling of your query (`set profiling = 1; select * from my_table; show profile for query 1;`)

Answer (score 1):

I just was looking for an answer to the same problem: nothing was going into the query cache. My database name did not contain a minus (-) but did instead contain a period (.). I dumped the database -- happily it's still small as it's only in development -- and restored it into a different database with no . in the name, and the query cache is working fine now.